# Apache Camel Salesforce Component Making A REST call to download binary files

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-camel, salesforce

I'm trying to implement a rest callout to Salesforce using camel-salesforce component in spring boot and wanted to know if I have to make a GET call to Salesforce content api over https that downloads various types of files of sizes close to 50 MB which component option would I choose? I read the documentation here
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/salesforce-component.html and got confused.

I tried the below in my camel config

```
salesforce:apexCall?apexMethod=GET&amp;apexUrl=/services/data/v49.0/connect/files/545435435/content&amp;rawPayload=true&amp;sObjectClass=org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.dto.CreateSObjectResult"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [raw operation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/salesforce-component.html#raw).

It returns an `InputStream` which ideally will contain the file you fetched.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jeremy. I tried this
`salesforce:raw?rawMethod=GET&amp;rawPath=/services/data/v49.0/connect/files/545435435/content`
and it gave me error - 
`Failed to resolve endpoint.
There are 2 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{rawMethod=GET, rawPath=/services/data/v49.0/connect/files/545435435/content}]`

Comment: What Camel version are you using?

Comment: camel-core version is-> 2.23.2.fuse-7_10_1-00008-redhat-00001

Comment: That version is very old and unsupported. More importantly, the salesforce raw operation was added much later.